# documentation/specfication for emacs variant of ctags format

Tags: ctags

Where can I find some thorough documentation / a specification for the Emacs ctags format? The ultimate goal here is to make it easier to generate a tags file in parallel (preferably using a tool like `xargs` or GNU Parallel).

Somewhat confusingly, there are two very different formats commonly called "ctags". One of which is used by `vi` and its workalikes.

example (from Perl 5 source code using `ctags -f- op.c | head -n 3`):

```
AAS_DANGEROUS   op.c    /^    AAS_DANGEROUS       = 0x080, \/* an op (other than the above)$/;" e   enum:__anon1file:
AAS_DEFAV   op.c    /^    AAS_DEFAV           = 0x200  \/* contains just a single '@_' on RHS *\/$/;"   e   enum:__anon1    file:
AAS_LEX_AGG op.c    /^    AAS_LEX_AGG         = 0x008, \/* @lexical or %lexical aggregate *\/$/;"   e   enum:__anon1    file:
```

This format has the advantage of being line-oriented and storing the symbol first, so work can be efficiently parallelized

```
find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \
   | xargs -I% -n100 -P8 ctags -f- % \
   | env LC_ALL=C sort > tags
```

By contrast, the Emacs variant of the ctags format is a little bit harder to decipher since, among other things, it uses non-printable characters internally.

```
File Edit Options Buffers Tools Hexl Help
87654321  0011 2233 4455 6677 8899 aabb ccdd eeff  0123456789abcdef
00000000: 0c0a 6f70 2e63 2c31 3935 3131 0a23 6465  ..op.c,19511.#de
00000010: 6669 6e65 2050 4552 4c5f 494e 5f4f 505f  fine PERL_IN_OP_
00000020: 437f 5045 524c 5f49 4e5f 4f50 5f43 0131  C.PERL_IN_OP_C.1
```

It also uses byte offsets instead of a search string. It also mentions the file name once at the start of a "stanza" corresponding to each file rather than having each line stand on its own.

The closest I was able to find to documentation of the internal format (rather than the kinds of pattern in source codes that emacs recognizes) was https://stackoverflow.com/q/1990579/931154 .

Comment: I'd just look at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, this is actually a pretty quick way to parallelize the work for generating a `tags` file. Here are two strategies that I've found effective. You can rewrite either shell fragment to use `xargs` instead of `parallel`.

1. Use GNU Parallel with the `--files` option to generate separate temporary files for each job.
2. swap `^L` and `\n` when processing the files and then swap them back when you're done aggregating the output streams of separate `ctags` jobs.

(1) This relies on the --files feature of GNU Parallel, which redirects the stdout of each job into a separate temporary file and then, after all the jobs are finished, writes each temporary file to stdout.

```
cat $(find . |
    awk '/[.](h|cc|hh|cpp|hpp|c)$/ {print}' |
    parallel --no-notice -n100 --files 'ctags -e -f - {}'
) > TAGS
```

(2) Different "stanzas" corresponding to a source file in the etags format are separated using the `^L` character (`\f` in another notation). You can swap `^L` and `\n`, use line-oriented tools, and then swap them back (using `tr '\n\f' '\f\n'`). The result will look something like this if you use GNU Parallel. (Sorting the resulting lines is not strictly necessary)

```
find . |
    awk '/[.](h|cc|hh|cpp|hpp|c)/ {print}' |
    parallel --no-notice -n100 'ctags -e -f - {}' '|' "tr '\\n\\f' '\\f\\n'" | 
    env LC_ALL=C sort |
    tr '\n\f' '\f\n' >TAGS
```